# Normalization in the Abelian Chern-Simons action

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, topological-field-theory, normalization, topological-phase, chern-simons-theory

In all the places I looked (such as chapter 5 in the lecture notes of David tong (http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qhe.html) and E. Witten (https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.07698)) the action for the Abelian $(U(1))$ Chern-Simons theory is defined as
$$
S=\frac{k}{4 \pi} \int_{M_3} A \wedge dA.
$$
The action is supposed to be gauge invariant when $k$ is an integer. But I do not understand why that is the case. There are three related questions that I would like to ask.

1. Under a guage transformation $A \to A+d\alpha$, the action changes by $\delta S= \frac{k}{4\pi}\int d\alpha \wedge dA$. Now, we have $\int dA = 2\pi Z$ and also $\int d\alpha =2\pi Z$. This should give us $\delta S=k\pi Z$. This should require that $k$ should be an even integer. Why $k$ should just be any integer ?
2. Actually there is another way to compute $\delta S$ (I think this is what is done in Witten's lecture notes: https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.07698 ): For an arbitrary variation of $A\to A+\delta A$ the action changes as $\delta S=\frac{k}{2\pi}\int \delta A \wedge dA$. Now, in the case when $\delta A$ is gauge variation $\delta A =d\alpha$ we have $\delta S=2\pi k$ so this gives us $k\in Z$. But I cannot quite understand why we are getting different answers.
3. To motivate the quantization of  $k$, Witten (in https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.07698 page 32-33) evaluates the Chern-Simons action with $M_3=S_1\times S_2$ in the presence of magnetic monople. He mentions that *"This is actually a slightly tricky calculation, because in the presence of nonvanishing magnetic flux on $S_2$ the gauge field Ai has a Dirac string singularity"*. He computed the integral indirectly to arrive at the result. I want to to know if there is a direct way to arrive at the result (For example by diving the $S_2$ into two patches (to take into account the dirac string) and requiring that on the overlap, the gauge fields differ by a pure gauge. I have actually tried this, but this does not resolve the issue. But may be I have missed something).

Any help regarding this issue will be hugely appreciated.